# Multiple forms in tables, multiple submit buttons. Can I do it with just PHP and HTML?

Tags: php

I am trying to create a schedule for a Tae Kwon Do school, and I would like the admins to be able to CRUD their table .

This is how I would like for it to look:

[image]

and here is my code right now:

```
<?php require_once("../../includes/initialize.php"); ?>
<?php if (!$session->is_logged_in()) { redirect_to("login.php"); } ?>
<?php
  $schedules = Schedule::find_all();
  ?>
<?php include_layout_template('admin_header.php'); ?>

<h2>Schedule</h2>
<?php  
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
    $schedule = Schedule::find_by_id($_GET['id']);
        if($schedule && $schedule->delete()) {
            $session->message("The line was deleted.");
            redirect_to('schedule.php');
        }else{
            $session->message("The line could not be deleted.");
            redirect_to('schedule.php');
        }
}
?>

<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $schedule = new Schedule();
    $schedule->belt = $_POST['belt'];
    $schedule->age = $_POST['age'];
    $schedule->monday = $_POST['monday'];
    $schedule->tuesday = $_POST['tuesday'];
    $schedule->wednesday = $_POST['wednesday'];
    $schedule->thursday = $_POST['thursday'];
    $schedule->friday = $_POST['friday'];
    $schedule->saturday = $_POST['saturday'];
    if($schedule->save()) {
        $session->message("line added successfully.");
        redirect_to('schedule.php');
    } else {
        $message = join("<<br />", $schedule->errors);
    }
}
?>

<?php 
if(isset($_POST['update'])){
    $schedule = Schedule::find_by_id($_POST['id']);
    $schedule->belt = $_POST['belt'];
    $schedule->age = $_POST['age'];
    $schedule->monday = $_POST['monday'];
    $schedule->tuesday = $_POST['tuesday'];
    $schedule->wednesday = $_POST['wednesday'];
    $schedule->thursday = $_POST['thursday'];
    $schedule->friday = $_POST['friday'];
    $schedule->saturday = $_POST['saturday'];
    if($schedule->save()) {
        $session->message("line updated successfully.");
        redirect_to('schedule.php');
    } else {
        $message = join("<<br />", $schedule->errors);
    }
}
?>

<?php echo output_message($message); ?>
<table id="schedule">
     <tr>
        <th>Belt</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Monday</th>
        <th>Tuesday</th>
        <th>Wednesday</th>
        <th>Thursday</th>
        <th>Friday</th>
        <th>Saturday</th>
        <th></th>
     </tr>
    <?php foreach($schedules as $schedule): ?>
    <tr>
        <form action="schedule.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $schedule->id;?>" />

        <td><input type="text" size="15" name="belt" value="<?php echo $schedule->belt; ?>" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" size="5" name="age" value="<?php echo $schedule->age; ?>" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" size="7" name="monday" value="<?php echo $schedule->monday; ?>" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" size="7" name="tuesday" value="<?php echo $schedule->tuesday; ?>" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" size="7" name="wednesday" value="<?php echo $schedule->wednesday; ?>" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" size="7" name="thursday" value="<?php echo $schedule->thursday; ?>" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" size="7" name="friday" value="<?php echo $schedule->friday; ?>" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" size="7" name="saturday" value="<?php echo $schedule->saturday; ?>" /></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="update" value="Update" /><input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');"/></td>
        </form>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach;?> 

    <tr>    
        <form action="schedule.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <td><input type="text" size="15" name="belt" value="" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" size="5" name="age" value="" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" size="7" name="monday" value="" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" size="7" name="tuesday" value="" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" size="7" name="wednesday" value="" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" size="7" name="thursday" value="" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" size="7" name="friday" value="" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" size="7" name="saturday" value="" /></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add new line" /></td>
        </form>
    </tr>
</table>

        <br /><br />

<?php include_layout_template('admin_footer.php'); ?>
```

I would love to make some additional enhancements, but I can't figure out this form. It was working fine up until I added the ability to update. Now when I add some new data into one of the rows, and click update - it doesn't give me a session message and doesn't update the field in the view (but I think it is in the DB).

Any advice would be appreciated. I imagine that I could fix this with some AJAX - but I haven't touched it in a while and frankly don't remember how...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it doesn't show the update on the screen is because

```
$schedules = Schedule::find_all();
```

is above the code to update. So $schedules doesn't get changed. I'd suggest changing

```
<?php foreach($schedules as $schedule): ?>
```

to

```
<?php foreach(Schedule::find_all() as $schedule): ?>
```

Comment: that definitely fixed it, thank you so much. It won't let me accept the answer yet but I will when I can.

Any idea why my "line updated successfully" message isn't being shown? On update success it is being passed to the message session...

Comment: nevermind, I was forgetting to return true when the update succeeded. thanks!